# North-American chipless credit card in France

Tags: trains, france, money, payment-cards, atms

I am moving to France from the USA in the next 1 week. I just read that North American chipless credit cards [will probably not work with several merchants](http://www.bankrate.com/finance/credit-cards/will-your-credit-card-work-abroad-1.aspx) in France and that they would most likely [get rejected in RER ticket kiosks](http://parisbytrain.com/paris-train-ticket-machine/).

I will arrive at Paris CDG and the picture of [people queuing up by an ATM is less than confidence promoting](http://anyportinastorm.proboards.com/thread/2565?page=1). I may not be able to get foreign currency before I leave, given the remote location of my US town.

In the first few hours or days of my being there, how do I avoid this potential pitfall of credit cards presumably being rejected?

Some of the other questions that I have read on this SE are:

- [Can US cards be used in countries with chip-and-pin system?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7968/2236)
- [Magnetic stripe credit cards in France](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13855/2236)

Comment: I have a chipless card and had no problem using it for the 4 days I was in Paris. It was common that the clerk would have to swipe the card, rather than me using the customer keypad, without the chip, but I was never unable to pay.

Comment: @Flimzy But I am guessing that my chipless credit card will not work at **automated** ticket kiosks? Or am I wrong on that count as well?

Comment: I'm trying to remember if I ever did that... it's possible I didn't, as I arrived with a small amount of cash (€100), and was with friends, so I may not have needed to use an ATM or other automated kiosk during my stay. You can always change cash at the airport or other currency exchange location. The rates are worse than an ATM, but will be better than having no money!

Comment: @Flimzy I am assuming that USD are next to worthless at magasins, restaurants, tabacs and boutiques at least until I have Euro?

Comment: I think some places accept USD, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: You should certainly be able to buy some Euro at a currency exchange place at your international departure airport. Presumably your flight doesn't go directly from your remote town to CDG.

Comment: @MeNoTalk I have referenced the post you mention in mine. The answer provided by it was inconclusive.

Comment: @drN I think the answers were fine. I do not think it is possible to list all shops in France along with their status whether then accept it or not. I prefer you adding a bounty on the old answer to improve it.

Comment: @MeNoTalk Good point on the "bounty on original question". Never thought of that. Should I delete this question if I were to do that (bounty on other question?)?

Comment: @drN you can leave it, it will help when searching in google or other search engines. You can flag it as duplicate.